# Custom Fields for Resources

Tags: ckan

For Datasets, you can always add custom fields from the Web interface ("Manage" -> "Edit Metadata"), but you can't seem to do this for Resources.

Is there similar functionality for Resources? Can one use it via the GET-able API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Web UI to add fields to the resources form. You could suggest it to the community and offer to work on it or fund it: https://github.com/ckan/ideas-and-roadmap

You can post extra fields to resources when you POST to the `package_create`/`package_update` APIs. The CKAN API is documented here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html

Put extra fields are just like other fields in a resource dictionary. For example, here's a resource you could POST to package_create where I've added a 'quality_rating' field which will be stored as an extra:

```
res_dict = {
    'package_id':'testpackage',
    'name': 'testresource',
    'description': 'A long description of my resource!',
    'format': 'CSV',
    'quality_rating': '10/10'
}
```

Comment: I've read this API documentation, but can't see how to add extra fields for resources, only datasets. For concreteness, consider ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create. Which parameter do I use to pass in extra field information?